Limit as $x\to3$ of $\frac{\sqrt{x-2}-1}{\sqrt[6]{x-2}-1}$?
I wanted to found the limit of this function. But I was not capable of obtaining a value for $x\to3 ^-$. However, I did find the value for the other side limit, its equal to $-9$.
$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by:
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      \frac{\sqrt{x-2}-1}{\sqrt[6]{x-2}-1} & x< 3 \\
      x^2\sin\frac{\pi x}2& x\geq 3
   \end{cases}
$$
Help will be appreciated, I don't know if the excercise is oddly defined or my algebra is not that good.

Hint : We know that $u^3-1=(u-1)*(u^2+u+1)$. Use that to split the numerator with $u=\sqrt[6]{x-2}$

Hint: as $h:=x-3\to0$, $(1+h)^a-1\sim ah$.

Let $t=(x-2)^\frac{1}{6}$ and then $t^3=\sqrt{x-2}$.
$\lim\limits_{x \to 3^{-}}f(x)=\lim\limits_ { \ t \to 1^{-}}\frac{t^3-1}{t-1}=\lim\limits_{\ t \to 1^{-} } t^2+t+1=3$

@TonyK I am not myself today...

Thanks a lot! I didn't knew about the substitution.

Applying L'Hopital's Rule
Since the limit takes the form  $ \frac{0}{0} $, we can differentiate the numerator and the denominator:
Differentiate the numerator: $
  \frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{x-2} - 1) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-2}}
  $
Differentiate the denominator
$
  \frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt[6]{x-2} - 1) = \frac{1}{6(x-2)^{5/6}}
  $
Now, evaluate the limit of the derivatives as x→3
$
\lim_{x \to 3^-} \frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-2}}}{\frac{1}{6(x-2)^{5/6}}} = \lim_{x \to 3^-} \frac{6(x-2)^{5/6}}{2\sqrt{x-2}} = \lim_{x \to 3^-} 3 \frac{(x-2)^{5/6}}{\sqrt{x-2}}
$
$
= \lim_{x \to 3^-} 3 (x-2)^{1/3}
$
As $ x \to 3^- $, x−2→1. So $ (x-2)^{1/3} \to 1^{1/3} = 1 $
Therefore, the limit is:
$
\lim_{x \to 3^-} 3 (x-2)^{1/3} = 3 \cdot 1 = 3
$
This suggests that $ \lim_{x \to 3^-} f(x) = 3 $

The question was tagged "limit without l'Hopital". Moreover, this question and your answer are duplicates.

@AnneBauval oh i only saw the problem without seeing the tags
